# Trying to write the output of mount in a file

Tags: command-line, bash, mount

I wrote a bash script to mount a certain network drive and now I would like the output to be written in the file log_mount.
This script was for testing purposes but does not work.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
address="srv01"
path="netstorage/testing"
folder="netstorage"
username="uname"
password="password"
mount -v -t cifs //$address/$path/ /mnt/$folder/ -o username=$username,password=$password >>log_mount
```

The command itself works fine, I just do not understand why it won't write to the file.

Comment: Is it `stdout` or `stderr`? (Try `2>>log_mount`)

Comment: The file `log_mnt` will be created in the current directory if the file doesn't exist, otherwise output will be appended to the existing file. Probably it helps if you use an absolut path to `log_mnt` ( e.g. `/home/username/log_mnt`) so that you exactly know where your `log_mnt`-file is located.

Comment: you can also make the output more verbose by adding up to 4 "v"s to the mount command

Comment: @FedonKadifeli already tried that didn't work

Comment: @mook765 the file exsists and is in the same directory

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Does your command have any output? What happens to that output? Is it still shown in the terminal? There's nothing wrong with your command, if what happens is that the file is created but is empty, that just means the command has no output printed to stdout. If you also tried `2>>` and that still created an empty file, then your command has no output on stderr either. Please [edit] your question and explain what you are expecting to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: Maybe the command acts differently in a script. You may try a login shell?

Answer (score 0):

If mount is successful then there is no output. The comments to your question have already pointed to output redirection. If not interested in details so much, but much after not missing a success you can add some extra verbosity like:

```
(echo -n "mounting ..  "; mount .. && echo -n "[ok] " || echo -n "[fail] "; date)>/tmp/logfile
```

and also redirect the error stream or just leave it.